# Deleted /.emacs.d/ and now Emacs won't work properly. How do I recreate/reset Emacs .emacs-folder?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I've been trying to get Emacs and Clojure to work for the last couple of hours but dammit if it doesn't want to work at all. So, in my blind rage I figured I should delete the .emacs.d/-folder with all the content. And since I'm using OS X I can't see the hidden files and I have no way of restoring them.

I'm also using the newest nightly build from emacsformacosx.com. Specifically the error is about the elpa/package.el-file.

So, ehm, I need help to get Emacs to work again, somehow reset it. And sorry if this question is in the wrong Stackexchange-site, I'm sort of desperate to get this to work. Or just plain mad that it doesn't. Bah.

Comment: "since I'm using OS X I can't see the hidden files and I have no way of restoring them."  Sorry if I'm missing something, but can't you **ls -la** in a terminal window?  You can at least see them, though not restore ones you've deleted.

Comment: Learn to control your rage.  It's a crucial part of what is affectionately known as the "emacs learning curve."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have a .emacs file in your home directory.  ELPA will stick

```
(when
    (load
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/package.el"))
  (package-initialize))
```

at the end of this file when it is installed.  That's what's probably causing the error.